# How could awk be made timezone aware?

Tags: text-processing, awk, date

A timestamp ([In layman terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp)) could be an ISO8601 string (generally the output of the POSIX specified `%FT%T` format) with a zone string added (Loosely, one of the two formats available in date, either `%Z` or `%z`).

Then, the timestamp string becomes an specific "point in time", i.e. not with an undefined local time (with at least 24 different possible different values).

Such "point in time" string could be converted to an epoch value (the result of a `+'%s'` format) with no loss of information.

For example, with input on columns 1 and 2 and the output on columns 3 and 4:

```
$ cat indate
2020-03-02T12:23:34 UTC         1583151814  2020-03-02T06:23:34CST-0600
2020-03-02T12:23:34 Z           1583151814  2020-03-02T06:23:34CST-0600
2020-03-02T12:23:34 EST         1583169814  2020-03-02T11:23:34CST-0600
2020-03-02T12:23:34 CST         1583173414  2020-03-02T12:23:34CST-0600
2020-03-02T12:23:34 AST         1583166214  2020-03-02T10:23:34CST-0600
2020-03-02T12:23:34 ADT         1583162614  2020-03-02T09:23:34CST-0600
2020-03-02T12:23:34 EDT         1583166214  2020-03-02T10:23:34CST-0600
2020-03-02T12:23:34 BST         1583148214  2020-03-02T05:23:34CST-0600
2020-03-02T12:23:34 IST         1583132014  2020-03-02T00:53:34CST-0600
2020-03-02T12:23:34 +00:00      1583151814  2020-03-02T06:23:34CST-0600
2020-03-02T12:23:34 -0400       1583166214  2020-03-02T10:23:34CST-0600
2020-03-02T12:23:34 -0800       1583180614  2020-03-02T14:23:34CST-0600
2020-03-02T12:23:34 +06:00      1583130214  2020-03-02T00:23:34CST-0600
```

The requested output should be the seconds since the epoch taking also the timezone into account and (if possible) the timestamp rewritten with `%Z%z` values.

It is known that GNU date is able to process this all by itself on colums 1 and 2 with:

```
$ date -f indate +%s
```

The question is: Is there a solution with awk?

The only way that I have been able to get that **in AWK** is by using GNU date, which involves a lot of re-formating, calling an external executable for each new line and getting it back in to awk. I believe that there is a way to call date only once, but still, that is an external executable.

Is there a better way **with awk**?

The awk script I have written:

```
$ cat tst.awk
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ \t:T-]*"}
     {

        cmd="date -d '\''"$1 $2"'\'' +'\''%s'\''";
        while ( ( cmd | getline fmtDate) > 0 ) {
            val = fmtDate
        }
        close(cmd);

        datestr=$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" 0 "
        print mktime(datestr),$1,$2,"\t",cmd,"\t",val

    }'  indate
```

And, the output, which seems correct (for a local time of EST):

```
$ ./tst.awk
1607012614 2020-12-03T12:23:34 UTC  date -d '2020-12-03T12:23:34 UTC' +'%s' 1606998214
1607012614 2020-12-03T12:23:34 Z    date -d '2020-12-03T12:23:34 Z' +'%s'   1606998214
1607012614 2020-12-03T12:23:34 EST  date -d '2020-12-03T12:23:34 EST' +'%s' 1607016214
1607012614 2020-12-03T12:23:34 EDT  date -d '2020-12-03T12:23:34 EDT' +'%s' 1607012614
1607012614 2020-12-03T12:23:34 BST  date -d '2020-12-03T12:23:34 BST' +'%s' 1606994614
1607012614 2020-12-03T12:23:34 IST  date -d '2020-12-03T12:23:34 IST' +'%s' 1606978414
1607012614 2020-12-03T12:23:34 +00:00   date -d '2020-12-03T12:23:34 +00:00' +'%s'  1606998214
1607012614 2020-12-03T12:23:34 -0400    date -d '2020-12-03T12:23:34 -0400' +'%s'   1607012614
1607012614 2020-12-03T12:23:34 -0800    date -d '2020-12-03T12:23:34 -0800' +'%s'   1607027014
1607012614 2020-12-03T12:23:34 +06:00   date -d '2020-12-03T12:23:34 +06:00' +'%s'  1606976614
```

Comment: Note that `mktime()` is a gawk extension. standard awk doesn't have datetime parsing / formatting builtin. You may want to look at proper generic programming languages like perl / ruby / tcl / python / php...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, I am looking at a generic programming language: AWK.

Answer (score 7):

The following is all about GNU awk for various extensions and is aware of the timezone in your environment but not directly in your data.

It's not entirely the output you wanted (idk if all of your TZ values are portable, in particular EDT, BST and IST, or need any additional massaging to be in a TZ format that awk likes - you'd have to investigate that further) but you can see below that we are using the TZ to affect the seconds since epoch output by doing this:

```
$ gawk '{
    dt = gensub(/\s+\S+$/,"",1); gsub(/[-:T]/," ",dt)
    tz = $NF
    if ( match(tz,/^([-+]?)([0-9]{2}):?([0-9]{2})$/,a) ) {
        tz = (a[1] == "-" ? "+" : "-") a[2] ":" a[3]
    }
    ENVIRON["TZ"] = tz

    epochSecs = mktime(dt)

    ENVIRON["TZ"] = "UTC"
    printf "%-30s ->  %10s  ->  %s UTC\n", $0, epochSecs, strftime("%F %T",epochSecs)
}' indate
2020-12-03T12:23:34 UTC        ->  1606998214  ->  2020-12-03 12:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 Z          ->  1606998214  ->  2020-12-03 12:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 EST        ->  1607016214  ->  2020-12-03 17:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 EDT        ->  1606998214  ->  2020-12-03 12:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 BST        ->  1606998214  ->  2020-12-03 12:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 IST        ->  1606998214  ->  2020-12-03 12:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 +00:00     ->  1606998214  ->  2020-12-03 12:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 -0400      ->  1607012614  ->  2020-12-03 16:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 -0800      ->  1607027014  ->  2020-12-03 20:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 +06:00     ->  1606976614  ->  2020-12-03 06:23:34 UTC
```

The above is relying on `mktime()` (and `strftime()` just for the output of UTC time from the derived epoch secs to make it easy to compare the timestamps) using the value of the `TZ` environment variable and on being able to change the value of `TZ` in the running awk scripts environment from inside that script which requires GNU awk version 4.2 or later.

Note that for the dates with numbers at the end in the input such as `2020-12-03T12:23:34 +06:00`, date is not using `+06:00` as a time zone, it's using it as a human-readable delta to be applied to the provided timestamp taken as UTC. You can see the difference if you use `date -d '2020-12-03T12:23:34 +06:00' +'%s'` (which outputs `1606976614`. which is `2020-12-03T12:23:34 UTC` - 6 hours) vs `TZ='+06:00' date -d '2020-12-03T12:23:34' +'%s'` (which outputs `1607019814`, which is `2020-12-03T12:23:34 UTC` + 6 hours).

So, we have to swap the sign on the `tz` above to have it treated the same way as `date` would treat it, i.e. a delta to apply to the timestamp after treating it as UTC, vs treating it as an actual timezone.

Interestingly, `date` behaves the same as gawk in terms of handling EDT, BST and IST timezones when the timezones are set in TZ vs provided as part of the timestamp string, but it also understandably fails on the numeric values that don't have a `:` in the middle when set in TZ:

```
$ while read -r ts tz; do
    printf '%s:\t %s  vs  %s\n' "$tz" "$(date +'%s' -d"$ts $tz")" $(TZ="$tz" date '+%s' -d"$ts")
done < indate
UTC:     1606998214  vs  1606998214
Z:   1606998214  vs  1606998214
EST:     1607016214  vs  1607016214
EDT:     1607012614  vs  1606998214
BST:     1606994614  vs  1606998214
IST:     1606978414  vs  1606998214
+00:00:  1606998214  vs  1606998214
-0400:   1607012614  vs  1606998214
-0800:   1607027014  vs  1606998214
+06:00:  1606976614  vs  1607019814
```

So it seems like there's some magic involved in `date -d` beyond just reading a timezone, which makes sense since it's described in [the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) as `mostly free format human readable date string` and can include strings like `next Thursday`.

You could, of course, write an awk script like this to map non-portable TZ values used in your data to portable ones (see https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/790263bc-bd30-48f1-af12-ed36055d718b/e5f17bfc-ecba-40bf-a04f-376bbb11e811/timezone.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones):

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN {
    tzmap["EST"] = "US/Eastern"
    tzmap["EDT"] = "-04:00"
    tzmap["BST"] = "+01:00"
    tzmap["IST"] = "Asia/Calcutta"
}
{
    dt = gensub(/\s+\S+$/,"",1); gsub(/[-:T]/," ",dt)
    tz = ( $NF in tzmap ? tzmap[$NF] : $NF )
    if ( match(tz,/^([-+]?)([0-9]{2}):?([0-9]{2})$/,a) ) {
        tz = (a[1] == "-" ? "+" : "-") a[2] ":" a[3]
    }
    ENVIRON["TZ"] = tz

    epochSecs = mktime(dt)

    ENVIRON["TZ"] = "UTC"
    printf "%-30s ->  %10s  ->  %s UTC\n", $0, epochSecs, strftime("%F %T",epochSecs)
}' indate
2020-12-03T12:23:34 UTC        ->  1606998214  ->  2020-12-03 12:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 Z          ->  1606998214  ->  2020-12-03 12:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 EST        ->  1607016214  ->  2020-12-03 17:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 EDT        ->  1607012614  ->  2020-12-03 16:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 BST        ->  1606994614  ->  2020-12-03 11:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 IST        ->  1606978414  ->  2020-12-03 06:53:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 +00:00     ->  1606998214  ->  2020-12-03 12:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 -0400      ->  1607012614  ->  2020-12-03 16:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 -0800      ->  1607027014  ->  2020-12-03 20:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 +06:00     ->  1606976614  ->  2020-12-03 06:23:34 UTC
```

You'd just need to know in advance which of those TZs could appear in your input file, which it seems like you would.

*Note: The above commands were run on a Mac. When running the same commands in cygwin none of the numeric `TZ` values were understood by `date` or `awk`. I suspect that is a cygwin issue rather than any other kind of portabilty issue.*

After discussion with the [timezone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) provider, Paul Eggert, I wrote a shell script that uses bash plus POSIX tools to generate a file of mappings from timezone abbreviations to offsets and database names if you have the timezone database directory structure and correct version of the `zdump` tool:

```
$ cat maptzabbrs
#!/usr/bin/env bash

usage() {
    cat <<'!'
Usage:  maptzabbrs [overrides]
        maptzabbrs --help

Given a timezone database directory like /usr/share/zoneinfo/posix and
a version of zdump (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/zdump.8.html)
that supports "-i", this will output a tab-separated table of
Abbreviation -> Offset -> Database Names where the list of Database Names
associated with each Abbreviation+Offset will be comma-separated.
Database names without an alphanumeric abbreviation are ignored.

Input: "zdump -i" outputs blank line separated records like:

        TZ="/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/America/Chicago"
        -       -       -06     CST
        2022-03-13      03      -05     CDT     1
        2022-11-06      01      -06     CST

        TZ="/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Asia/Hong_Kong"
        -       -       +08     HKT

Stdout Output (all alphanumeric abbreviations):

        CDT     -04:00  America/Havana,Cuba
        CDT     -05:00  America/Bahia_Banderas,America/Chicago,...
        CST     +08:00  Asia/Chongqing,Asia/Chungking,...
        CST     -05:00  America/Havana,Cuba
        CST     -06:00  America/Bahia_Banderas,...,America/Chicago,...
        HKT     +08:00  Asia/Hong_Kong,Hongkong

Stderr Output (only abbreviations with multiple offsets):

        Warning: abbreviation(s) with multiple alternative offsets:
        CDT     -04:00  America/Havana,Cuba
        CDT     -05:00  America/Bahia_Banderas,America/Chicago,...
        CST     +08:00  Asia/Chongqing,Asia/Chungking,...
        CST     -05:00  America/Havana,Cuba
        CST     -06:00  America/Bahia_Banderas,...,America/Chicago,...

If this tool is called with an argument, that is taken as file of overrides
to disambiguate abbreviations such as the above that would otherwise have
multiple offsets, e.g. if the file "overrides" contained (third column
optional and ignored):

        CDT     -05:00  America/Bahia_Banderas,America/Chicago,...
        CST     -06:00  America/Bahia_Banderas,...,America/Chicago,...

Then calling the tool as

        maptzabbrs overrides

would restrict the stdout for CST and CDT to only be for the stated
offsets and they would not be reported as ambiguous on stderr.

References:
        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database

Thanks to the TZ dabatase provider Paul Eggert for background
information and suggestions on how to make this work.
!
}

if [[ "$1" == "--help" ]]; then
    usage
    exit
fi

: tzDir=${tzDir:='/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix'}
(( $# > 0 )) && overrides=$1 || overrides='/dev/null'

ofs='\t'
printf "Zone${ofs}Offset${ofs}Names\n"

find "$tzDir" -type f | sort | xargs zdump -c 2022,2023 -i |
awk -v tzDir="$tzDir" -v OFS="$ofs" '
    FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
        abbr2offset[$1] = $2
        next
    }
    NF {
        if ( sub(/^TZ="/,"") ) {
            sub(/".*/,"")
            name = substr($0,length(tzDir)+2)
        }
        else {
            # change [[:alpha:]] to [[a-zA-Z]] if not supported
            abbr = ($4 ~ /[[:alpha:]]/ ? $4 : "")
            offset = sprintf("%s:%02d",substr($3,1,3),substr($3,4))

            if ( abbr != "" ) {
                abbrs[abbr]
                if ( !(abbr in abbr2offset) ||
                     ((abbr in abbr2offset) && (abbr2offset[abbr] == offset)) ) {
                    if ( !seen_offset[abbr,offset]++ ) {
                        abbrsOffsets[abbr,++numOffsets[abbr]] = offset
                    }
                    if ( !seen_name[abbr,offset,name]++ ) {
                        abbrsNames[abbr,offset,++numNames[abbr,offset]] = name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        for ( abbr in abbrs ) {
            for ( offsetNr=1; offsetNr<=numOffsets[abbr]; offsetNr++ ) {
                offset = abbrsOffsets[abbr,offsetNr]
                for ( nameNr=1; nameNr<=numNames[abbr,offset]; nameNr++ ) {
                    name = abbrsNames[abbr,offset,nameNr]
                    names = (nameNr>1 ? names "," : "") name
                }
                print abbr, offset, names | "sort"

                if ( numOffsets[abbr] > 1 ) {
                    gotAmbiguous = 1
                    ambiguous[abbr OFS offset] = names
                }
            }
        }
        close("sort")

        if ( gotAmbiguous ) {
            print "Warning: abbreviation(s) with multiple alternative offsets:" | "cat>&2"
            close("cat>&2")
            for ( abbrOffset in ambiguous ) {
                print abbrOffset, ambiguous[abbrOffset] | "sort>&2"
            }
            close("sort>&2")
        }
    }
' "$overrides" -
```

The above should take about half a second to run and given this overrides file:

```
$ cat overrides
CDT     -05:00  America/Bahia_Banderas,America/Chicago,America/Indiana/Knox,America/Indiana/Tell_City,America/Knox_IN,America/Matamoros,America/Menominee,America/Merida,America/Mexico_City,America/Monterrey,America/North_Dakota/Beulah,America/North_Dakota/Center,America/North_Dakota/New_Salem,America/Rainy_River,America/Rankin_Inlet,America/Resolute,America/Winnipeg,CST6CDT,Canada/Central,Mexico/General,US/Central,US/Indiana-Starke
CST     -06:00  America/Bahia_Banderas,America/Belize,America/Chicago,America/Costa_Rica,America/El_Salvador,America/Guatemala,America/Indiana/Knox,America/Indiana/Tell_City,America/Knox_IN,America/Managua,America/Matamoros,America/Menominee,America/Merida,America/Mexico_City,America/Monterrey,America/North_Dakota/Beulah,America/North_Dakota/Center,America/North_Dakota/New_Salem,America/Rainy_River,America/Rankin_Inlet,America/Regina,America/Resolute,America/Swift_Current,America/Tegucigalpa,America/Winnipeg,CST6CDT,Canada/Central,Canada/Saskatchewan,Mexico/General,US/Central,US/Indiana-Starke
IST     +05:30  Asia/Calcutta,Asia/Kolkata
PST     -08:00  America/Ensenada,America/Los_Angeles,America/Santa_Isabel,America/Tijuana,America/Vancouver,Canada/Pacific,Mexico/BajaNorte,PST8PDT,US/Pacific
```

it produced this output on my machine:

```
$ /maptzabbrs overrides
Zone    Offset  Names
ACDT    +10:30  Australia/Adelaide,Australia/Broken_Hill,Australia/South,Australia/Yancowinna
ACST    +09:30  Australia/Adelaide,Australia/Broken_Hill,Australia/Darwin,Australia/North,Australia/South,Australia/Yancowinna
ADT     -03:00  America/Glace_Bay,America/Goose_Bay,America/Halifax,America/Moncton,America/Thule,Atlantic/Bermuda,Canada/Atlantic
AEDT    +11:00  Antarctica/Macquarie,Australia/ACT,Australia/Canberra,Australia/Currie,Australia/Hobart,Australia/Melbourne,Australia/NSW,Australia/Sydney,Australia/Tasmania,Australia/Victoria
AEST    +10:00  Antarctica/Macquarie,Australia/ACT,Australia/Brisbane,Australia/Canberra,Australia/Currie,Australia/Hobart,Australia/Lindeman,Australia/Melbourne,Australia/NSW,Australia/Queensland,Australia/Sydney,Australia/Tasmania,Australia/Victoria
AKDT    -08:00  America/Anchorage,America/Juneau,America/Metlakatla,America/Nome,America/Sitka,America/Yakutat,US/Alaska
AKST    -09:00  America/Anchorage,America/Juneau,America/Metlakatla,America/Nome,America/Sitka,America/Yakutat,US/Alaska
AST     -04:00  America/Anguilla,America/Antigua,America/Aruba,America/Barbados,America/Blanc-Sablon,America/Curacao,America/Dominica,America/Glace_Bay,America/Goose_Bay,America/Grenada,America/Guadeloupe,America/Halifax,America/Kralendijk,America/Lower_Princes,America/Marigot,America/Martinique,America/Moncton,America/Montserrat,America/Port_of_Spain,America/Puerto_Rico,America/Santo_Domingo,America/St_Barthelemy,America/St_Kitts,America/St_Lucia,America/St_Thomas,America/St_Vincent,America/Thule,America/Tortola,America/Virgin,Atlantic/Bermuda,Canada/Atlantic
AWST    +08:00  Australia/Perth,Australia/West
BST     +01:00  Europe/Belfast,Europe/Guernsey,Europe/Isle_of_Man,Europe/Jersey,Europe/London,GB,GB-Eire
CAT     +02:00  Africa/Blantyre,Africa/Bujumbura,Africa/Gaborone,Africa/Harare,Africa/Juba,Africa/Khartoum,Africa/Kigali,Africa/Lubumbashi,Africa/Lusaka,Africa/Maputo,Africa/Windhoek
CDT     -05:00  America/Bahia_Banderas,America/Chicago,America/Indiana/Knox,America/Indiana/Tell_City,America/Knox_IN,America/Matamoros,America/Menominee,America/Merida,America/Mexico_City,America/Monterrey,America/North_Dakota/Beulah,America/North_Dakota/Center,America/North_Dakota/New_Salem,America/Rainy_River,America/Rankin_Inlet,America/Resolute,America/Winnipeg,CST6CDT,Canada/Central,Mexico/General,US/Central,US/Indiana-Starke
CEST    +02:00  Africa/Ceuta,Arctic/Longyearbyen,CET,Europe/Amsterdam,Europe/Andorra,Europe/Belgrade,Europe/Berlin,Europe/Bratislava,Europe/Brussels,Europe/Budapest,Europe/Busingen,Europe/Copenhagen,Europe/Gibraltar,Europe/Ljubljana,Europe/Luxembourg,Europe/Madrid,Europe/Malta,Europe/Monaco,Europe/Oslo,Europe/Paris,Europe/Podgorica,Europe/Prague,Europe/Rome,Europe/San_Marino,Europe/Sarajevo,Europe/Skopje,Europe/Stockholm,Europe/Tirane,Europe/Vaduz,Europe/Vatican,Europe/Vienna,Europe/Warsaw,Europe/Zagreb,Europe/Zurich,Poland
CET     +01:00  Africa/Algiers,Africa/Ceuta,Africa/Tunis,Arctic/Longyearbyen,CET,Europe/Amsterdam,Europe/Andorra,Europe/Belgrade,Europe/Berlin,Europe/Bratislava,Europe/Brussels,Europe/Budapest,Europe/Busingen,Europe/Copenhagen,Europe/Gibraltar,Europe/Ljubljana,Europe/Luxembourg,Europe/Madrid,Europe/Malta,Europe/Monaco,Europe/Oslo,Europe/Paris,Europe/Podgorica,Europe/Prague,Europe/Rome,Europe/San_Marino,Europe/Sarajevo,Europe/Skopje,Europe/Stockholm,Europe/Tirane,Europe/Vaduz,Europe/Vatican,Europe/Vienna,Europe/Warsaw,Europe/Zagreb,Europe/Zurich,Poland
CST     -06:00  America/Bahia_Banderas,America/Belize,America/Chicago,America/Costa_Rica,America/El_Salvador,America/Guatemala,America/Indiana/Knox,America/Indiana/Tell_City,America/Knox_IN,America/Managua,America/Matamoros,America/Menominee,America/Merida,America/Mexico_City,America/Monterrey,America/North_Dakota/Beulah,America/North_Dakota/Center,America/North_Dakota/New_Salem,America/Rainy_River,America/Rankin_Inlet,America/Regina,America/Resolute,America/Swift_Current,America/Tegucigalpa,America/Winnipeg,CST6CDT,Canada/Central,Canada/Saskatchewan,Mexico/General,US/Central,US/Indiana-Starke
ChST    +10:00  Pacific/Guam,Pacific/Saipan
EAT     +03:00  Africa/Addis_Ababa,Africa/Asmara,Africa/Asmera,Africa/Dar_es_Salaam,Africa/Djibouti,Africa/Kampala,Africa/Mogadishu,Africa/Nairobi,Indian/Antananarivo,Indian/Comoro,Indian/Mayotte
EDT     -04:00  America/Detroit,America/Fort_Wayne,America/Grand_Turk,America/Indiana/Indianapolis,America/Indiana/Marengo,America/Indiana/Petersburg,America/Indiana/Vevay,America/Indiana/Vincennes,America/Indiana/Winamac,America/Indianapolis,America/Iqaluit,America/Kentucky/Louisville,America/Kentucky/Monticello,America/Louisville,America/Montreal,America/Nassau,America/New_York,America/Nipigon,America/Pangnirtung,America/Port-au-Prince,America/Thunder_Bay,America/Toronto,Canada/Eastern,EST5EDT,US/East-Indiana,US/Eastern,US/Michigan
EEST    +03:00  Asia/Amman,Asia/Beirut,Asia/Damascus,Asia/Famagusta,Asia/Gaza,Asia/Hebron,Asia/Nicosia,EET,Europe/Athens,Europe/Bucharest,Europe/Chisinau,Europe/Helsinki,Europe/Kiev,Europe/Mariehamn,Europe/Nicosia,Europe/Riga,Europe/Sofia,Europe/Tallinn,Europe/Uzhgorod,Europe/Vilnius,Europe/Zaporozhye
EET     +02:00  Africa/Cairo,Africa/Tripoli,Asia/Amman,Asia/Beirut,Asia/Damascus,Asia/Famagusta,Asia/Gaza,Asia/Hebron,Asia/Nicosia,EET,Egypt,Europe/Athens,Europe/Bucharest,Europe/Chisinau,Europe/Helsinki,Europe/Kaliningrad,Europe/Kiev,Europe/Mariehamn,Europe/Nicosia,Europe/Riga,Europe/Sofia,Europe/Tallinn,Europe/Uzhgorod,Europe/Vilnius,Europe/Zaporozhye,Libya
EST     -05:00  America/Atikokan,America/Cancun,America/Cayman,America/Coral_Harbour,America/Detroit,America/Fort_Wayne,America/Grand_Turk,America/Indiana/Indianapolis,America/Indiana/Marengo,America/Indiana/Petersburg,America/Indiana/Vevay,America/Indiana/Vincennes,America/Indiana/Winamac,America/Indianapolis,America/Iqaluit,America/Jamaica,America/Kentucky/Louisville,America/Kentucky/Monticello,America/Louisville,America/Montreal,America/Nassau,America/New_York,America/Nipigon,America/Panama,America/Pangnirtung,America/Port-au-Prince,America/Thunder_Bay,America/Toronto,Canada/Eastern,EST,EST5EDT,Jamaica,US/East-Indiana,US/Eastern,US/Michigan
GMT     +00:00  Africa/Abidjan,Africa/Accra,Africa/Bamako,Africa/Banjul,Africa/Bissau,Africa/Conakry,Africa/Dakar,Africa/Lome,Africa/Monrovia,Africa/Nouakchott,Africa/Ouagadougou,Africa/Sao_Tome,Africa/Timbuktu,America/Danmarkshavn,Atlantic/Reykjavik,Atlantic/St_Helena,Eire,Etc/GMT,Etc/GMT+0,Etc/GMT-0,Etc/GMT0,Etc/Greenwich,Europe/Belfast,Europe/Dublin,Europe/Guernsey,Europe/Isle_of_Man,Europe/Jersey,Europe/London,GB,GB-Eire,GMT,GMT+0,GMT-0,GMT0,Greenwich,Iceland
HDT     -09:00  America/Adak,America/Atka,US/Aleutian
HKT     +08:00  Asia/Hong_Kong,Hongkong
HST     -10:00  America/Adak,America/Atka,HST,Pacific/Honolulu,Pacific/Johnston,US/Aleutian,US/Hawaii
IDT     +03:00  Asia/Jerusalem,Asia/Tel_Aviv,Israel
IST     +05:30  Asia/Calcutta,Asia/Kolkata
JST     +09:00  Asia/Tokyo,Japan
KST     +09:00  Asia/Pyongyang,Asia/Seoul,ROK
MDT     -06:00  America/Boise,America/Cambridge_Bay,America/Chihuahua,America/Denver,America/Edmonton,America/Inuvik,America/Mazatlan,America/Ojinaga,America/Shiprock,America/Yellowknife,Canada/Mountain,MST7MDT,Mexico/BajaSur,Navajo,US/Mountain
MEST    +02:00  MET
MET     +01:00  MET
MSK     +03:00  Europe/Moscow,Europe/Simferopol,Europe/Tiraspol,W-SU
MST     -07:00  America/Boise,America/Cambridge_Bay,America/Chihuahua,America/Creston,America/Dawson,America/Dawson_Creek,America/Denver,America/Edmonton,America/Fort_Nelson,America/Hermosillo,America/Inuvik,America/Mazatlan,America/Ojinaga,America/Phoenix,America/Shiprock,America/Whitehorse,America/Yellowknife,Canada/Mountain,Canada/Yukon,MST,MST7MDT,Mexico/BajaSur,Navajo,US/Arizona,US/Mountain
NDT     -02:30  America/St_Johns,Canada/Newfoundland
NST     -03:30  America/St_Johns,Canada/Newfoundland
NZDT    +13:00  Antarctica/McMurdo,Antarctica/South_Pole,NZ,Pacific/Auckland
NZST    +12:00  Antarctica/McMurdo,Antarctica/South_Pole,NZ,Pacific/Auckland
PDT     -07:00  America/Ensenada,America/Los_Angeles,America/Santa_Isabel,America/Tijuana,America/Vancouver,Canada/Pacific,Mexico/BajaNorte,PST8PDT,US/Pacific
PKT     +05:00  Asia/Karachi
PST     -08:00  America/Ensenada,America/Los_Angeles,America/Santa_Isabel,America/Tijuana,America/Vancouver,Canada/Pacific,Mexico/BajaNorte,PST8PDT,US/Pacific
SAST    +02:00  Africa/Johannesburg,Africa/Maseru,Africa/Mbabane
SST     -11:00  Pacific/Pago_Pago,Pacific/Samoa,US/Samoa
UTC     +00:00  Etc/UCT,Etc/UTC,Etc/Universal,Etc/Zulu,UCT,UTC,Universal,Zulu
WAT     +01:00  Africa/Bangui,Africa/Brazzaville,Africa/Douala,Africa/Kinshasa,Africa/Lagos,Africa/Libreville,Africa/Luanda,Africa/Malabo,Africa/Ndjamena,Africa/Niamey,Africa/Porto-Novo
WEST    +01:00  Atlantic/Canary,Atlantic/Faeroe,Atlantic/Faroe,Atlantic/Madeira,Europe/Lisbon,Portugal,WET
WET     +00:00  Atlantic/Canary,Atlantic/Faeroe,Atlantic/Faroe,Atlantic/Madeira,Europe/Lisbon,Portugal,WET
WIB     +07:00  Asia/Jakarta,Asia/Pontianak
WIT     +09:00  Asia/Jayapura
WITA    +08:00  Asia/Makassar,Asia/Ujung_Pandang
```

You can read the output of that tool in an awk script that requires those mappings to populate the `tzmap[]` array I used in my previous awk script above instead of manually populating it.

Comment: Ed, as always, wonderful answer!

Answer (score 2):

> The only way that I have been able to get that is by using GNU date, which involves a lot of re-formating, calling an external executable for each new line and getting it back in to awk.

GNU date can read dates from a file:

```
% cat foo.dates
2020-12-03T12:23:34 UTC
2020-12-03T12:23:34 Z
2020-12-03T12:23:34 EST
2020-12-03T12:23:34 EDT
2020-12-03T12:23:34 BST
2020-12-03T12:23:34 IST
2020-12-03T12:23:34 +00:00
2020-12-03T12:23:34 -0400
2020-12-03T12:23:34 -0800
2020-12-03T12:23:34 +06:00

% date --file foo.dates +%s
1606998214
1606998214
1607016214
1607012614
1606994614
1606978414
1606998214
1607012614
1607027014
1606976614
```

Even if it didn't, this seems like a job for `xargs`, not awk:

```
% xargs < foo.dates -n 1 -d '\n' date +%s -d
1606998214
1606998214
1607016214
1607012614
1606994614
1606978414
1606998214
1607012614
1607027014
1606976614
```

Comment: The point is how to make **awk** do it? I know that GNU date is quite versatile, but awk doesn't seem to be able to help here, which is odd, given that most of the time it is the most powerful of grep, sed, or ed. Is GNU date the only solution?

Comment: @QuartzCristal arguably Python is far more powerful than awk and even it  doesn't have much in the way of general purpose date parsing (in the stdlib anyway). For some things, purpose-built tools like `date` really often don't have equivalents.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Appreciated. @muru

Comment: Perl has several libraries for parsing dates, and perl functionality is a superset of awk.  Generally, awk can be directly translated to perl.